# How to handle error or exception on a Class (DriveApp)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Does anyone have a sample of code for how I can handle an error thrown by the following call?

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'reader',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': 'wxy@zzzzzzzz.com'
   },
   fileID,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
```

In certain circumstances, I get the following error and would simply like to ignore and continue my script. Error is:

> API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Bad
>   Request. User message: "You are trying to invite wxy@zzzzzzzz.com
>   Since there is no Google account associated with this email address,
>   you must check the "Notify people" box to invite this recipient."
>   (line 6, file "Testtwo")

Comment: Look up the try...catch clause under Javascript on Mozilla's Development Network(MDN).

Comment: `'sendNotificationEmails': 'true'`

Comment: As the @TheMaster points out, reading the error message carefully will often provide you with or point you towards the answer to your question.

Comment: realize I can set notification to true but don't want to send notifications.  I guess I would need logic to determine to send notification to those that don't have a google account but not sure how to get that.  Will research.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the `@` with `indexOf` and then slice the substring to get the domain of each email. Then use an `if` and set `true` or `false` depending of if it is `gmail.com` or not. Supposing you have the emails in an array:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){

    var sign = emails[i].indexOf('@');
    var domain = emails[i].slice(sign+1);


    if (domain == 'gmail.com'){

      parameter = {
        'sendNotificationEmails': 'true'
      }

    } else {
      parameter = {
        'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
      }
    }

    Drive.Permissions.insert(
      {
        'role': 'reader',
        'type': 'user',
        'value': emails[i]
      },
      fileId,      
      parameter);

  }

}
```

**References**:

- [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)
- [slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)